# Flutter : Good way of adding borders to CustomPaint

Tags: flutter, custom-painting, flutter-custompainter

I am trying to create a more complex customPaint and want to add a border to it.
From the picture you can see the shape (In blue) and the partial border (in white)

The way I am creating the white border is with a secondary customPaint right now.
My question is, **is there an easier way of adding a border to the existing customPaint**, as doing the corners of the rectangle can be annoying by itself and doesn't seem like an elegant way of doing it.

[image]

My code right now, without the border

```
      Path.combine(
        PathOperation.intersect,
        Path()
          ..addRRect(RRect.fromLTRBR(
              xCanvasLeft,
              xCanvasTop,
              xCanvasRight,
              xCanvasBot,
              const Radius.circular(canvasRadius))),
        Path()
          ..addOval(Rect.fromCircle(
              center: Offset(xHole, yHoleTop),
              radius: holeRadius))
          ..addOval(Rect.fromCircle(
              center: Offset(xHole,
                  yHoleBot),
              radius: holeRadius))
          ..close(),
      ),
      paint,
    );
```

EDIT: I am also wondering how resource heavy custom paint is?

Answer (score 0):

I simply use the same painter for adding the border with the stroke width property.

```
Paint paintBorder = Paint()
  ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
  ..strokeWidth = 6.0
  ..color = Colors.blue;
Paint paintFill = Paint();
```

Then while drawing the path just draw the fill before the border like this

```
canvas.drawPath(path, paintFill);
canvas.drawPath(path, paintBorder);
```